# python oneliner, more than one way to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-liner

Interactively one can do:

```
$ python3 -c "
> import time
> while True:
>   print('Two more weeks')
>   time.sleep(1)
> 
> "
Two more weeks
Two more weeks
Two more weeks
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
KeyboardInterrupt

$
```

Now, is there a feasible way to create and run the "script" above,
**without** actually writing the code to a file?

Note; I believe that **indented** code and "compound statements" are problematic here!

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Mainly create **one-liners** in feasible manner... First thing: i didn't realize piping into python was ONE way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't really clarify anything. Why must this be a one-liner? How are you planning on executing the code? What is your *actual use-case*. Just asking to convert some random, bespoke code to a one-liner is not really on-topic for stack overflow. Questions for code golf have their own stack-exchange network. Note. you can in theory convert *any* Python code into one giant lambda expression, which can theoretically go into one giant line. There are converters that already do that.

Comment: You didn't write anything to a file above. What you have isn't one *physical* line, but it's one *logical* line. The newlines are all part of the quoted argument to the `-c` option.

Comment: @chepner yes, but it is also **interactive**, to be useful it should not require that, so be practically us(e?)able in everyday scripting.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The code (above) itself is not "interesting", **the practical ways of creating oneliners** using python was my main aim; from the multitude of questions regarding this it is apparent that the practical solution to the problem has not (edit:)been revealed in clear detail.

Comment: There's nothing interactive about it; the shell is simply displaying the secondary prompt to indicate that the parser hasn't yet seen an unquoted newline that indicates the end of the command.

Comment: Well "interactive", in bash, in the meaning that you are typing code on the keyboard... e.g. NOT running a script.

Comment: Now; I'm not a native english speaker, so **wording**
 might be a problem here.

Comment: If you aren't typing at the terminal, and you aren't reading anything from a file... what's left?

Comment: Place the above snippet in a bash script; how? and remember; oneliner!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running bash on Linux you could paste something like this to your shell:

```
echo """
import time
while 1:
  print('Two more weeks')
  time.sleep(1)
""" | python
```

With one line you could also do:

```
echo -e "import time\nwhile 1:\n  print('Two more weeks')\n  time.sleep(1)" | python
```

Comment: python*3* seems to be required ;.)

Comment: So... is there more ways to do this? This the simplest?

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, this monstrosity will fit easily on one line:

```py
$ python3 -c "while True: import time; print('one more week'); time.sleep(1)"
```

Comment: =) nicely repeating code that shouldn't

Comment: ... and by that bypassing the problem with "import time;" before "while"